# What's a rule of thumb to decide if it's necessary to respond to a short "thank you" email in a formal context? (see example)

Tags: conversation, email, formal-language

I wasn't sure about how to construct the question but with a conversation as example it'll be clearer:

> *Chuck*: Hi Joe, as we've talked before, I'm sending you the requested file. Sincerely, Chuck.
>
> *Joe*: Thanks Chuck, I'm present it to the Dev team this morning. Thanks, Joe.
>
> *Chuck*: Thank you Joe. As a side comment, I just noticed that the file had a little error, so I'm attaching here the correct version. Regards,
> Chuck.
>
> *Joe*: Hi Chuck, Thanks. I will send the new version to the team. Thanks again, Billy.

I think Chuck doesn't really need to answer again, am I wrong?

Comment: You might benefit from this Stack Exchange site as well: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In line 3, as written I can't tell if Chuck is sending the file to the Dev Team or to you. Depending on this, line 4 may be wrong. Also line 4 does not say where you will send the file. So at least add some wording to clearly state what is getting sent where. Also in line 3, you should state what "it" is.

Comment: @user3169 I've edited the question based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems less about English, per se, and more about culture, specifically workplace culture and etiquette.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I could have posted on WorkPlace community, but I decided to do it here because my concern is how does it work only in English (on the US if I have to be more specific) and not in any culture.

Comment: @rewobs: The problem is that it varies a fair amount between English-speaking countries, is not limited to English, and even varies within the US itself, between companies.

Comment: It is clear what is going where now. But you can't say "I'm present", I would stick with "I'm Sending". You could say "I'm presenting", but when transmitting by email "sending" is best.

Comment: I agree that this question, as worded, should be on workplace SE. You can specify in the question that you're an English language learner and you're specifically interested in US workplace culture. If the answer you get there is 'yes, answer', then we can probably help you with any problems you might have phrasing a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, my experience has been that Chuck does not need to answer yet again. The only possible thing he could write at that point (assuming there are no more file errors to correct) would be "You're welcome!" And in the workplace, US workers are tending to eliminate etiquette in favor of productivity.

I would refer you to Sanebox's Email hacks and tips. Specifically #57
http://www.sanebox.com/l/100-email-hacks#no36